# Significance of sum and product of roots

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

I've been able to find formulas all over the place for the sum and product of roots, but I haven't found anything that explains the significance of what they mean or how to interpret them to further gain understanding of the polynomial under evaluation. Is there any physical meaning? Do the values have any significance?

For example, I have a $4$<sup>th</sup> order complex polynomial in $ \mathbb{Z} $, for which I find the real part of the $4$ roots add up to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. I'm wondering what the significance of the sum being $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is? To me it's a "buzz" number.

Comment: The question as stated does not sound clear. Given a polinomial $P(x)$, a complex root $\overline{x}\in \mathbbl C$ of $P$ is a complex number such that $P(\overline x)=0$. Why would you expect it to depend on $x$, when you are substituting $x$ with $\overline x$ in the polynomial and checking if it equals zero?

Comment: [symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial)

Comment: I cleaned up my example. I think the fact I used `x` as a variable caused some confusion

Answer (score 1):

The roots of a polynomial in $x$ are the values you can plug in for $x$ such that the polynomial takes the value $0$. So the first part of your last paragraph doesn't make much sense, since roots are special values of $x$.

The sum and product of roots of a quadratic polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$ are $-b/a$ and $c/a$ respectively. For example, if you were told that the roots of a quadratic polynomial were $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $x=\frac{1}{4}$, then the sum is $x=\frac{3}{4}$ and the product is $\frac{1}{8}$, so you can immediately say that one such polynomial is $8x^2 - 6x + 1$ without having to expand $\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)$.

(Note that the roots of a polynomial don't change if you multiply the entire expression, which was what I did.)

The more general formula for higher-order polynomials is given by [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but what is the significance of $\frac{3}{4}$? Does it tell you anything about the polynomial? Is there more meaning to it other than "it's just the sum"? Same questions for the product.

Comment: It tells me that the coefficient of the linear term of the quadratic polynomial is equal to $-\frac{3}{4}$ (provided we set the coefficient of the leading term to be 1). So I actually got $x^2 - \frac{3}{4}x + \frac{1}{8}$ and multiplied through by 8.

Comment: I was just looking over Vieta's formulas and I follow you now. Beyond the math, I guess the physical interpretation would be more related to the order of the polynomial. Does Vieta's formulas extend to complex polynomials in Z?

Comment: I don't know whether polynomials whose coefficients aren't from a subset of its variables' domain can even be well-defined, but otherwise it should hold true for any polynomial over an integral domain.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/polynomials-sums-products-roots.html

I had to google it, but I would check out that link. It does give you information about coefficients in the polynomial, which I think kind of makes sense, because you make a polynomial by multiplying linear factors together (assuming that a polynomial is reducible in your chosen field, but in the complex numbers, you don't have to worry about that).